# First element that comes AFTER sibling OR descendant?

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to always find the **first** `<ul>` that comes after `<h2>`, preferrably without looping, using a single Jsoup select() statement.

For example, that `<ul>` can be a sibling of `<h2>` as shown in this HTML snippet:

```
<!-- lots of things can come before -->

<h2 class="C" id="S3">
<button class="B">Click Me</button>
<span id="targetSpan">Target Span</span>
</h2>

<ul>
<li> List item 1</li>
<li> List item 2</li>
</ul>

<!-- lots of things can come after -->
```

Or it can be a descendant (not necessarily a direct child!) of a sibling of `<h2>`. The sibling may or may not be the first sibling element after `<h2>`, but `<ul>` is *always* the first `<ul>` after that `<h2>`. For example:

```
<!-- lots of things can come before -->

<h2 class="C" id="S3">
<button class="B">Click Me</button>
<span id="targetSpan">Target Span</span>
</h2>

<div>
<ul>
<li> List item 1</li>
<li> List item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- lots of things can come after -->
```

I can find the `<h2>` easily:

```
Element h2 = select("h2 > span#targetSpan").first().parent();
```

But once I have h2, how do I find the first `<ul>` after it? (could be sibling or descendant, I don't control that HTML code)

Comment: quite related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30089307/274502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid your own loop. You must iterate through all next element siblings until you find the next `<ul>`:

```
  Element h2next = h2.nextElementSibling();
  do {
    ul = h2next.select("ul:not([class]))").first();         
  } while (h2next!=null && ul==null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the method

```
nextElementSibling()
```

and get the UL from that.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling()